# Entity Framework inserts existing navigation property entity

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and I keep getting the following error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AssignmentType'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AssignmentType'.

As you see I tried to change the state of the entity `AssignmentType` to `unchanged`. When I assign the entity `Assignment` the foreign key of `AssignmentType` and then set the navigation property `AssignmentType` to null, I still get the same error (in the foreach loop of `Assignments`, not in the `Comments` foreach loop).

Where does Entity Framework keeping track of the entity `AssignmentType` and why does it still think it's a new entity and not an existing one?

There is a many-to-many relationship between the entity `Reporting` and `Assignment`.

```
    [Route("")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Add(ReportingDTO data)
    {            
        Reporting reporting = new Reporting { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Date = DateTime.Now };                     

        foreach (Assignment assignment in data.Assignments)
        {
            _db.Entry(assignment.AssignmentType).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

            if (assignment.Reporting.Count > 0)
            {
                _db.Entry(assignment).State = EntityState.Added;
                _db.Entry(assignment).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            reporting.Assignment.Add(assignment);
        }

        foreach (Comment comment in data.Comments)
        {
            comment.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            comment.AssignmentID = comment.Assignment.ID;
            comment.Assignment = null;
            comment.ReportingID= reporting.ID;
        }

        using(var transaction = _db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            _db.Reporting.Add(reporting);
            _db.Comments.AddRange(data.Comments);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            transaction.Commit();
        }

        return Ok(reporting);
    }
```

`Reporting.cs`

```
[Table("Reporting")]
public partial class Reporting
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Reporting()
    {
        Assignment= new HashSet<Assignment>();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid ID{ get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime Date{ get; set; }  

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Assignment> Assignment{ get; set; }
}
```

`Assignment.cs`

```
[Table("Assignment")]
public partial class Assignment
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Assignment()
    {
        Reporting = new HashSet<Reporting>();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid OID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid AssignmentTypeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Project { get; set; }

    public bool Completed { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AssignmentTypeID")]
    public virtual AssignmentType AssignmentType { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Reporting> Reporting { get; set; }
}
```

`AssignmentType`

```
[Table("AssignmentType")]
public partial class AssignmentType
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}
```

Comment: Do you have a foreign key like: Assignment.AssignmentTypeId?

Comment: Yes I do. In the ReportingDTO this field is equal to null.

Comment: Can you post your data model?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult Add(ReportingDTO data)
{            
    Reporting reporting = new Reporting { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Date = DateTime.Now };                     

    foreach (Assignment assignment in data.Assignments)
    {
        if (assignment.ID != null)
        {
            _db.Assignments.Attach(assignment);
            _db.Entry(assignment).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else 
        {
            assignment.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        }

        if (assignment.AssignmentType != null)
        {
            assignment.AssignmentTypeID = assignment.AssignmentType.ID;
            assignment.AssignmentType = null;
        }
    }

    reporting.Assignment.AddRange(data.Assignments);

    foreach (Comment comment in data.Comments)
    {
        comment.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
        comment.AssignmentID = comment.Assignment.ID;
        comment.Assignment = null;
        comment.ReportingID = reporting.ID;
    }

    _db.Reporting.Add(reporting);
    _db.Comments.AddRange(data.Comments);
    _db.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(reporting);
}
```

All of your `Entry()` operations are useless in your context, except if you are updating an entity. In that case, you must `Attach()` the updated entity before updating its state.

Plus, to answer your initial question: EF adds a new AssignmentType because it has lost tracks of the existing one. Your Controller is constructed every time a request hit it, so your DbContext is also constructed every time. When you create a new DbContext, it has no knowledge of previous operations, like returning an `Assignment` or whatever (it's also the case if you specify `AsNoTracking()` during your query). In other words, if the entity is not tracked by the DbContext, then EF will try to add it.
To prevent that, you can (and really should) use the foreign keys instead of the navigation properties. Or you can `Attach()` every known entity (but it's useless if you have foreign keys). For ManyToMany relationships, you have to query the database before adding/updating a new entity, otherwise, you will have doubloons.

Or, you can also use what I call "link tables". It's just a class that's between your two primary classes. EF already does it for all your ManyToMany relationships (check your database). Basicaly, it goes something like :

```
public class A 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual List<AB> ABs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public virtual List<AB> BAs {get; set; }
}

public class AB
{
    public int AId {get;set;}
    public virtual A {get; set;}

    public int BId {get;set;}
    public virtual B {get; set;}
}
```

With that way, you can just add a new AB (or delete one) with `_db.ABs.Add(new AB{AId = 1, BId = 2})` without taking care of the rest.

Comment: If I only add the if statement and then add it to the reporting (like you did) I still get the same error as mentioned. Also I should mention that there can be new assignments or updated ones.

Comment: You mean that you want to add or update assignment in a single method? Plus adding a reporting and comments?

Comment: Yes correct. The Users goes through a wizard and in the end he saves the reporting, which contains all this data.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Now the method handles new and updated assignments. By the way, you really should avoid this kind of logic. It's usually recommended to have "atomic" operations (maybe with repositories), because it's easier to maintain and to debug.

Comment: How would you do this to avoid this kind of logic? Because I often have this scenario where I have to do this. Thanks for your help

Comment: Having a method that "does everything" is usually bad and is against the principle of "separation of concerns" which is OOP. In short terms, here, your method `Add` receives a request, process the data, saves it to the database and sends a response. Ideally, it should only call other methods to do every other things that are not receiving a request and sending a response. I'm not gonna go further, but you can have a look here : https://chsakell.com/2015/02/15/asp-net-mvc-solution-architecture-best-practices/

Comment: Alright I will have a look at it. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: No problem, but is my solution working? Do you still have bugs?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes I finally fixed it even though your answer didn't solve it. The problem was an existing Assignment, which means it is already assigned to an existing Reporting (many-to-many), so this Reporting also contained an existing AssignmentType. In the end I solved in with setting the Reporting property of the existing Assignment to null.